# Counting Circuits length $k$ on complete graph of $N$ vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

First, how do I count the number of circuits of length $k$ on $K_n$...and

Second, what is the rationale?

---

Right now, I am thinking that you've got $n$ choices, then $n-1$, $n-2$, $n-3$...but then you have $n-3$ or $n-2$ if you turn around and hit one of your earlier vertices...and I'm lost.

I got the number of walks of length $k$ by that reasoning...but I don't have a clue as to how to consider this problem...

Comment: Does your definition of circuit allow repetition of vertices?  So on $K_6$ is $1-2-3-1-4-1$ a circuit?  It does not repeat any edges.

Comment: Definition I just got: 

only restriction is that it ends where it starts.  I think that means it's a walk whose endpoint is the start point (in which case I've got it).

I'll leave it up if you want to answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can reuse edges, you have $n-1$ choices at each stage until step $k-2$.  From step $k-2$, you can't go back to start.  Whether you have $n-2$ or $n-1$ choices depends on whether you are at the start point at step $k-2$.